# Cypher query syntax error (reduce function)

Tags: syntax, cypher, reduce

I successfully made this Cypher query:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///order_data.csv' AS row
MERGE (c:Customer {customerId: row.MBR_ID, lastname: split(row.MBR_ID, "\_")\[0\]})
MERGE (s:Store {storeId: row.STORE_ID})
MERGE (p:Product {productId: row.PRD_ID, productName:row.PRD_NAME,productPrice:row.AMOUNT})
MERGE (s)-\[:SELLS\]-\>(p)
MERGE (c)-\[r:ORDERED{orderId:row.ORD_ID,    status:row.STATUS,date:row.SERV_DT,address:row.DELIV_ADDR}\]-\>(p)
```

And then I wanted to create a query returning all customers-store they visited:

```
MATCH (c:Customer)
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT c) AS customers
MATCH (s:Store)
WITH customers, s
OPTIONAL MATCH (c:Customer)-\[:ORDERED\]-\>(:Product)\<-\[:SELLS\]-(s)
WITH customers, s, c, COUNT(\*) AS count
WITH customers, s.storeId AS storeId, REDUCE(m = {}, c IN COLLECT(c) | m + {c.customerId: COALESCE(count, 0)}) AS counts
WITH customers, storeId, \[COALESCE(counts\[c.customerId\], 0) | c IN customers\] AS row
WITH storeId, COLLECT(row) AS matrix
WITH \[i IN RANGE(0, SIZE(matrix) - 1) | apoc.convert.toString(i) + ": " + apoc.convert.toString(matrix\[i\])\] AS output
RETURN output
```

but this query keeps giving me following error.

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError
Invalid input '{': expected "+" or "-" (line 7, column 76 (offset: 271))
"WITH customers, s.storeId AS storeId, REDUCE(m = {}, c IN COLLECT(c) | m + {c.customerId: COALESCE(count, 0)}) AS counts"
```

So i tried changing this line:

```
WITH customers, s.storeId AS storeId, REDUCE(m = {}, c IN COLLECT(c) | m + c.customerId: COALESCE(count, 0)) AS count
```

But it also has syntax error. Can anyone help me how to created proper cypher query?

Answer (score 0):

Cypher does not let you insert entries into an existing map. Also, Cypher does not let you dynamically set the property key when updating a map. However, the APOC function [apoc.map.setEntry](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/overview/apoc.map/apoc.map.setEntry/) can do both.

Instead of this:

```
WITH customers, s.storeId AS storeId, REDUCE(
  m = {}, c IN COLLECT(c) | m + {c.customerId: COALESCE(count, 0)}) AS counts
```

you can use `apoc.map.setEntry` to update the `m` map like this:

```
WITH customers, s.storeId AS storeId, REDUCE(
  m = {}, c IN COLLECT(c) | apoc.map.setEntry(m, c.customerId,  COALESCE(count, 0))) AS counts
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I installed APOC library and could use map function